# Button not working when I use update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 bootstrap tabs in a page. In the first and third tab buttons they are not working but a button in the second tab works fine. In the second tab I have an update panel to post back a dropdown because I want to show like bootstrap modal script and a button at second tab is working fine. Can you tell me why it's happening and how can I do this?

My question is very confusing to explain. I want to use about why a button in tab is not working but in the second tab is working fine. And when I do function in second tab finish a button in first tab is working. Why is happening? I am very confused. Thank you very much.

this is code in .aspx with function modal:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <%--modal  --%>   
    <button type="button" id="aaa" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">เพิ่มรายการใหม่</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="download" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="downloadlabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="downloadlabel">
                    <asp:Label ID="usrl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="detail" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <strong>Request Section</strong><br /><br />                         
                    </p>                        
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat ="server">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="formItem">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"><b>Item Code: </b></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="itm_code" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                        
                                <div class="formItem">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"><b>Item Description: </b></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="itm_desc" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formItem">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Order Category: </b></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ord_cat" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ord_cat_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Chosse Order Category"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                 
                                <div class="formItem">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Order Subcategory / Department in Lab: </b></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ord_subCat" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Chosse Order Subcategory"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formItem">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server"><b>Billing Group: </b></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ord_bg" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ord_bg_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Chosse Billing Group"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formItem">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server"><b>Billing SubGroup: </b></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ord_bsg" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Chosse Billing Sub Group"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Service Cat: </b></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ord_svc" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Alias Name / Synonym in Lab: </b></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ord_asn" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Cost Price: </b></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ord_cp" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <asp:Label runat="server"><b>OPD Price: </b></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="OPD_price" size="7" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:Label runat="server"><b>IPD Price: </b></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="IPD_price" size="7" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Tourist Price: </b></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TOU_price" size="7" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server"><b>File upload</b></asp:Label>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />
                            <p class="help-block" style="color: #FF852C">โปรดระบุ เอกสารแนบท้ายเพิ่มเติมกรณี (ถ้ามี)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Send to DF: </b></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ord_sdf" runat="server" CssClass="required">                                       
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ord_sdf" ErrorMessage="Please select some other choice.">
                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="formItem">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server"><b>Remark: </b></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ord_rmk" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>                       
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_insert" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="INSERT ITEM" runat="server" OnClick="btn_insert_Click" />         
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

code in tab 1

```
<div class="tab-content">                 
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <div class="search">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="group-search">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" Text="Item Code : " runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Font-Bold ="true"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="search_ic" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" Text="Item Description : " runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Font-Bold ="true"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="search_id" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>                            
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_search" Text="Search" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btn_search_Click" />
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_alert" Text="กรุณากรอก Item Code หรือ Item Description" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%--gridview for update--%>
        <div class="meddle2">
            <asp:GridView ID="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                OnDataBound="gridview_DataBound" 
                OnRowCancelingEdit="gridview_RowCancelingEdit" 
                OnRowEditing="gridview_RowEditing" OnRowUpdated="gridview_RowUpdated" 
                CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" ButtonType="Button" HeaderStyle-Width="80">
                        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary"></ControlStyle>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="80px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:CommandField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No." HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblnum"  runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.num") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Code" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblIC" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.item_code") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ic" runat="server" size="6" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.item_code") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.item_des") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_id" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.item_des") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Existing OPD Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEOP" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.eop") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_eop" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.eop") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Existing IPD Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEIP" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.eip") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_eip" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.eip") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Existing Tourist Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblETP" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.etp") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_etp" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.etp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New OPD Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNOP" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.nop") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_nop" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.nop") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New IPD Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNIP" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.nip") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_nip" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.nip") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Tourist Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNTP" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ntp") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ntp" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ntp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Margin OPD Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmop" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.mop") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_mop" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.mop") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Margin IPD Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmip" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.mip") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_mip" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.mip") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Margin Tourist Price" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D4E6ED">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmtp" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.mtp") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_mtp" runat="server" size="10" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.mtp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm. You're saying that there are 3 tabs out of which buttons of Tab1 & Tab3 are not working. However, the button of Tab2 works fine. And all these buttons are kept inside UpdatePanel. Buttons like, btnSearch from your Tab1 i.e., outside of GridView.

Comment: all of button in tab2 are kept outside updatePanel inside panel have 4 dropdown becuase i want to refresh them to get data in sql from code behide in this case is work fine.Button outside updatePanel in tab2 is work fine.but all button in tab1 & tab3 is not working is working then i submit solution with insert button in tab2.Are you under stand me,MR.P.K

Comment: button in tab1&3 is not postback

Comment: That means for Tab1 & Tab3 button click the page will not be posted back. If that is so these events will eventually get executed when a Postback finally occurs, which is happening when you click the button of Tab2. You need to have the post back on otherwise the server will never get the ClientRequest. Why have you disabled the PostBack for these Buttons? If you don't wan't to refresh the entire page then, keep them inside the Updatepanel. @user3001046

Comment: keep button in tab2 inside UpdatePanel ?

Comment: Are the buttons in Tab1 & Tab3 inside UpdatePanel??

Comment: no tab1 & 3 i not use updatePanel.button command in gridview at tab 1 is work fine . i very confuse why other button is not work but button command field in gridview at tap1 is work fine ?

Comment: See, there are always 2 components of Web app. One clientside and the other is server-side. When a user clicks any button on client-side its postback needs to be enabled to transfer the message to the server. So for both the buttons enable their Postbacks and yes you can also put them inside UpdatePanel

Comment: i think the problem is not updatePanel. i think the problem is modal in bootstrap

Comment: i know why all button in another is not post back because textbox in tab 2 is requird if textbox in tab 2 is empty the button is not post back